# Quadcopter takeoff when low throttle /w PID

Tags: quadcopter, pid

I'm making my own quad controller from scratch. I have fixed one axis on a "pendulum" so that only one axis can move freely ( + mode).
Let's say that I have 0 throttle. As you know PID output is added or taken away from throttle value on each motor.

My values of PID output are one instance let's say 5. (Quadcopter is laying at 5 degrees angle). Even in that case, one motor will spin at 5 speed, while other will be at -5 (won't move).

I'm asking beacuse when I add throttle to my quad and if I angle it at 10 degrees, it bounces on the other side and then again back, untill I add at least half throttle, which is kida agressive and I can't imagine this scenario with 4 motors.
So is there any way I can compensate this values?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the sensor data and the corresponding pid controller outputs? You said the compensation is quite aggressive, is the oscillation slow or fast. Your P gain might be too high. Lastly before tuning the PID gains of the pitch, roll and yaw controller, your base throttle must be set FIRST such that the quadcopter is floating and not sitting/resting on the stick, pole or string you used to isolate the movement to one axis.